# Can we make a minor tweak to the SFF chat CSS?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, chat

[image: rep count] [image: rep count without highlighting]

Left is highlighted text, Right is without the text being highlighted.

Because of the black background we use in SFF the rep count is never displayed properly.

[image: white rep count]

I suggest we simply change the rep flair to white.

[image]

Granted it's not really important at all, but it's a trivial change (depending on who manages the CSS)

Comment: You just *had* to use @Wad as an example ;)

Comment: @N_Soong He makes lots of oneboxing pics and gifs, that's why!

Comment: He was the only example within a full chat window. @N_Soong

Comment: Can't they make the ratings text white instead?

Comment: @Politank-Z I've edited to make it clearer that we should change the rep flair to white.

Answer (score 10):

This is now implemented as of chat build 341.